# Terraform - Getting error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Simply I'm trying to adopt some project tags to an existing internet gateway, by using data statements

```
data "aws_internet_gateway"    "internet_gateway"  {
   filter {
       name   = "attachment.vpc-id"
       values = [ aws_default_vpc.network[0].id ]
   }

   tags = var.tags
}
```

I've also checked with aws cli, here is the output

```
aws ec2 describe-internet-gateways
{
    "InternetGateways": [
        {
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "State": "available",
                    "VpcId": "vpc-***"
                }
            ],
            "InternetGatewayId": "igw-***",
            "OwnerId": "***",
            "Tags": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The filter I've used were in the example of terraform official documentation web page
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/internet_gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `tags` section from the Terraform data lookup. You are instructing Terraform to search for an internet gateway that has those tags, but as you can see in the CLI output the internet gateway doesn't have any tags assigned to it.

On a Terraform `resource` element, specifying `tags` would cause it to assign those tags to the resource, but on a `data` element specifying `tags` causes Terraform to use the tag values as part of the search it performs.

---

If it still doesn't work, you will need to verify that the value of `aws_default_vpc.network[0].id`  is what you are expecting, i.e. the same value as `VpcId` in the CLI output.

Comment: Now I see, thank you @Mark B. Can you suggest me the way to give a tags to default Internet Gateway?

Comment: Instead of referencing the internet gateway using a `data` element, you could reference it using a `resource` element, and import the current state using `terraform import`, after which Terraform could do things like assign tags to the resource.